# NHibernate query cache not working when using join

Tags: nhibernate, caching

When this gets called two times, the second invocation doesn't re-run the query on the database, the query caching works.

```
var query = from p in session.Query<Product>() 
            where p.YearIntroduced >= 0
            select p;

query = query.Cacheable();    

var t = query.ToList();
```

However, when I put some join on the query, the query cache is not working anymore, hence when this is invoked two times, the query is invoked on database two times too:

```
var query = from p in session.Query<Product>()

            join l in session.Query<ProductLanguage>() 
            on p.ProductId equals l.ProductId  

            where p.YearIntroduced >= 0
            select new { p, l };

query = query.Cacheable();

var t = query.ToList();
```

Might be a dumb question, is query caching can work on one table only, hence when adding a join, the query is not cacheable anymore?

What's the solution to make a query cacheable even it has a join?

---

Another oddity, the query caching with join will work if I remove the where clause. When this gets called two times, the second invocation doesn't re-run the query on database, the query caching works

```
var query = from p in session.Query<Product>()

            join l in session.Query<ProductLanguage>() 
            on p.ProductId equals l.ProductId  

            select new { p, l };

query = query.Cacheable();

var t = query.ToList();
```

But what's the use of a query when you can't put a where clause on it?

Is this an NHibernate bug, or am I just using query caching the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, put the Where clause on the final part of the query:

```
var query = from p in session.Query<Product>()

            join l in session.Query<ProductLanguage>() 
            on p.ProductId equals l.ProductId  

            select new { p, l };

query = query.Where(x => x.p.ProductId && x.l.LanguageCode == "en").Cacheable();

var t = query.ToList();
```